# Validating respective textarea in a questionnaire based on the option selected using ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

First of all, Thanks in advance,

I am designing an questionnaire which has 3-5 radio buttons and one comment box for each and every questions. Some of the options are mandatory, so that the user must fill some comments or else he cannot fill other questions. Both the names of radio button and textarea are the question_id and the value of radio button is the checked value. The names are stored as array so to insert in the db while submitting the form.
The input fields are

```
<input type='radio' name='ans_val[<?php echo $qid; ?>]' value='<?php echo $gans; ?>' />    
<textarea rows='3' name='cmnt[<?php echo $qid; ?>]' id="req"></textarea>
```

I used ajax to find whether the selected option is mandatory or not, because the options are stored in the database. I was able to view the passed value while selecting an option and the result of the query which executed to check the mandatory option. The ajax code I used is

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
        $('input:radio').click(function(){    
            var ans_id = $(this).attr('value');    
            var q_id = $(this).attr('name');    
            var dataString = 'id='+ans_id;    
            $.ajax({    
                type: "POST",    
                data: dataString,    
                url: "ans_chq.php",    
                success: function(data){    
                    $('body').append(dataString);    
                   // $('textarea').html(dataString);    
                }    
            });    
        });    
    });
```

In ans_chq.php, when the user selects a mandatory option '$mandatory' will become '1' else '0'.

I would like to know, how to return the variable $mandatory from the other page to the current page and how to validate respective textarea based on the options selected...

Please help me with this...

Comment: just echo it and it will come as data.

Comment: :D. Great. Thank you Suchit. I didn't know that actually. And for validating the text area I used 
$('cmnt[q_id]').prop('required',true);
But it makes all text area mandatory. Is it possible to pass a name like this???

Comment: this you are doing in jquery or ??.

Comment: when you use $ it means jquery.the ajax which you are using is jquery ajax.

Comment: should i post it in answer or comment.

Comment: I don't know what I an saying. :D . You can post it as an answer.. and thank you ..

Comment: let me know if you need any thing else.

Comment: and if answer solves your problem the mark it checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have seperate id's for each field then do this:

```
    $("#elementId").prop("required", "true");// here elementId is id of your input field.and id should be distinct for each input
```

if you have class for each field then do this:

```
  $(".elementId").prop("required", "true");// here elementId is class of your input field.and class need not to be unique.
```

if you are using input fields with name then try this:

```
  $("input[name='q_id']").prop("required", "true");// here q_id is name of the input field.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But it is not making the textarea mandatory.
I tried like this too... $("textarea[name='q_id']").prop("required", "true");

Comment: @Sajin give a class to all text area and try like this.     $('.myTextarea').prop('required',true); // class='myTextarea' in text area.

Comment: Yeah, I did that using id, and that makes all textarea mandatory. Also I am using this code inside the success : funtion(data){}. Could that be the reason?

Comment: no this part occurs when the ajax call is over and here you will receive the data to use.any ways your problem is solved or not.please read about ajax in jquery site for more info.